# PowerBI Matrix hide column header when displayed as rows

Tags: matrix, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a Power BI matrix defined as below. It has a column header and a number of values.
[image]

The value fields are configured to `Show Values to rows` so they are rendered as rows instead of columns.
[image]

My question now is how to hide the first column of the matrix so I show only the column header and the numbers:
[image]

I'm using PowerBI version `2.116`. Appreciate any advice!

I did see this [article](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/How-can-i-hide-first-Column-in-the-Matrix/m-p/375570) recommending to turn off word wrapping then reduce the column width to zero but my UI doesn't have those options. I'm guessing it's because the article is using a `Table` while I'm using a `Matrix` and values are displayed as rows?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HcOTQcMFmhc

Comment: Thank you, @AshokAnumula. I don't think this is applicable. What I'm trying to hide is the header, not the value.

Comment: Have you tried turning off text wrapping and then reducing the column width so it no longer shows?

Comment: I did see one article recommending that but my UI doesn't have those options to adjust the column width for some reason. :(